# How to use aggregate function in Mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have upgraded php5 to php7. If I use mongoClient for mongodb connection it shows error.So I used following command.

`$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://".MONGOHOST.":27017");`

By using above command I can able to connect db.Now problem is In php5, I used aggregate function.It doesn't support in php7. Code used in php5 mentioned  below..

for db connection

`$m = new MongoClient('mongodb://'.MONGOHOST.'', array('username' => MONGOUSER, 'password' => MONGOPASS, 'db'=> MONGODB ));
$db = $m->selectDB(MONGODB);`

to retrieve value from db:

```
$ops = array(
        array(
             '$match'=>array(
                "datetime"=>array('$gte'=>$start,'$lte'=>$end)
                )
            ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                "_id" => array("slotid" => '$slotid',"bidder" => '$bidder',"viewerid" => '$viewerid',"mediatype"=>'$mediatype'),"total" => array('$sum' => 1),"sitename" =>array('$addToSet' => '$sitename'),"aid" =>array('$addToSet' => '$accountid'),
                ),
            ),
        );
```

$reqbids = $db->requestbids->aggregate($ops);

How to do this is using mongo driver..I have searching 2 days,but didn't find the solution.

Comment: Wrong driver. What is commonly referred to as the [PHP-LIB](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) driver is the one intended for "userland" applications such as yours. The driver you have installed is the "low level" interface intended for "driver" authors writing their own higher level abstractions. Also see the [general overview](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.overview.php) for a simple graphical representation. Install the correct driver and start again. Methods such as aggregate exist there just as they do in other language drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use mongoClient.
You have to use **Mongodb manager**
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php

and for aggregate function use following code. [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php)

`$conn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1");`

```
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'aggregate' => 'collection',
    'pipeline' => [
        ['$group' => ['_id' => '$y', 'sum' => ['$sum' => '$x']]],
    ],
    'cursor' => new stdClass,
]);
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('db', $command);
```

Comment: I have changed my query above mentioned way.In php5 i used $addToSet but it not supported in php7..do you know how to do that